# Proof that Sharpe ratio of the benchmark is related to the maximal information ratio and Sharpe ratio

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio

I understand the economic logic behind it, that the active portfolio with the highest information ratio will also have the highest Sharpe ratio, but I can't see how 
$SR_B^2 = SR_P^2 - IR^2 $

Comment: It follows from "sum of independent variances" type reasoning. The portfolio return is equal to the benchmark return plus the tracking error. So $SR_P^2=SR_B^2+IR^2$

Comment: @noob2 that's the independence part I don't get, why wouldn't there be correlation between the bench and the active part?

Answer (score 2):

This has been shown in Grinold & Kahn (1999), Active Portfolio Management (p. 137ff). First, write $SR_P^2=SR_B^2+IR^2$ as  $\left(\frac{f_Q}{\sigma_Q}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{f_B}{\sigma_B}\right)^2 + IR^2$. Also note that the maximum information ratio is related to the portfolio's $Q$ Sharpe as follows: $IR=\frac{\alpha_Q}{\omega_Q}=SR\cdot \frac{\omega_Q}{\sigma_Q}$ where $\omega_Q$ is the residual risk. It is defined as $\omega_Q=\sqrt{\sigma_Q^2-\beta^2_Q \sigma^2_B}$ (see p. 50) where $\beta_Q=\frac{Cov[r_{Q},r_{B}]}{\sigma^2_B}$ is the beta of portfolio $Q$ and benchmark $B$.

Then, it follows that:

$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{f_Q}{\sigma_Q}\right)^2 &= \left(\frac{f_B}{\sigma_B}\right)^2 + IR^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{f_B}{\sigma_B}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{f_Q}{\sigma_Q} \right)^2 \left(\frac{\omega_Q}{\sigma_Q} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{f^2_B}{\sigma^2_B} + \frac{f^2_Q}{\sigma^2_Q} \cdot \frac{\sigma_Q^2-\beta^2_Q \sigma^2_B}{\sigma^2_Q} \\
&= \frac{f^2_B}{\sigma^2_B} + \frac{f^2_Q}{\sigma^2_Q} - \beta^2_B \frac{f^2_Q\sigma^2_B}{\sigma^4_Q} \\
&= \frac{f^2_B}{\sigma^2_B} + \frac{f^2_Q}{\sigma^2_Q} - \left(\frac{f_B\sigma^2_Q}{f_Q\sigma^2_B} \right)^2 \frac{f^2_Q\sigma^2_B}{\sigma^4_Q} \\
&= \frac{f^2_B}{\sigma^2_B} + \frac{f^2_Q}{\sigma^2_Q} - \frac{f^2_B}{\sigma^2_B} \\
&= \frac{f^2_Q}{\sigma^2_Q}
\end{align*}
$$

Note that the third last step can be solved using the statement about portfolio $Q$'s holdings (which is a mix of benchmark $B$ and managed portfolio $A$) on page 136.